# unable to import dump using "imp"

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, debian, oracleclient, ora-01034

I am trying to import into oracle using `imp` command and the output of the command is as below.

```
invincible:/home/invincible# imp

Import: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Aug 12 22:19:00 2010

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Username: n_data
Password: 

IMP-00058: ORACLE error 1034 encountered
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27123: unable to attach to shared memory segment
Linux Error: 13: Permission denied
IMP-00005: all allowable logon attempts failed
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
invincible:/home/invincible#
```

user name and password are correct(I am able to connect using sqldeveloper). I have granted `dba` access to `n_data`. All the environment variables are set (I ran `oracle_env.sh` before running `env` ). So what might be the problem? I am running oracle on debian.

Comment: I assume the database is on the same host because you haven't specified a tns alias - is ORACLE_SID set correctly?

Comment: yes, database is on the same host. ORACLE_SID is set to XE.

Comment: Can you run `sqlplus` from the same prompt and log in?  If so, can you run `select count(*) from all_objects;` and what does that query return?

Comment: No I am not able to run sqlplus(that is why I am using sqldeveloper)

Comment: Query output in sqldeveloper is :


COUNT(*)               
---------------------- 
12196                  

1 rows selected

Comment: Does the imp command work if you run it as the oracle user?

Comment: Are there any clues in the alert log?

Comment: Not able to run even as oracle.where to find alert log?

Comment: I know you've said that your environment is set up properly, but if you can't run SQL*Plus then something is wrong.  Can you post the values for $PATH, $ORACLE_HOME, $ORACLE_SID from the environment from which you're trying to run imp?

Comment: I second @dpbradley's comment.

Comment: Alert log is usually in $ORACLE_BASE/admim/<SID>/bdump/alert<SID>.log. However, it's not likely going to help if you can't even run sqlplus.

Comment: If the environment was that broken it wouldn't even find the imp (or sqlplus) binary, would it? Sounds more like a permission problem, maybe on a library (from past experience installing with a stupid umask). Try running `ldd $ORACLE_HOME/bin/imp` and see if it reports any missing libs, and if so check the perms on those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this blog post: [ORA-27123: unable to attach to shared memory segment](http://sabdarsyed.blogspot.com/2009/01/ora-27123-unable-to-attach-to-shared.html).

It describes same error as you have and problem was caused with incorrectly set permissions on oracle executable.

This is excerpt from the above blog post:

> Here the oracle file permission has
>   -rwxrwxr-x i.e. 775, but this file must have the permission -rwsr-s- -x
>   i.e. 6751
>
> Change the permissions for oracle
>   file.

```
$ cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
$ chmod 6751 oracle
$ ls -l oracle
-rwsr-s--x 1 oracle dba 119582976 Feb 3 2008 oracle
```

> After changing the permissions on
>   oracle executable file, all the users
>   are now able to connect to the
>   database without any errors.

Read blog post for detailed information.

Comment: Another favourite is libclntsh having the wrong permissions. But, in the comments on the original post it says he can't run SQL*Plus as the oracle owner either, which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests it is trying to connect to an instance on the same host that isn't there. Generally I'd say the database isn't actually up and running, but if you can connect with SQL Developer, it suggests it is. But check you are on the correct machine.

Also try

```
echo :${ORACLE_SID}:
```

There may be some stray character in the SID. If you are using XE, you want to see `:XE:` (in upper case, not mixed or lower)

Have you tried

```
imp n_data/password@XE
```